# @instance variable being updated via form submit but not via url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a view containing a form with a textbox. The value of the textbox should be reflected in the url.

When a value is entered in the textbox and submitted, the url and textbox reflect the value when the view is build.

When the value is changed in the url however I somehow can't get the textbox to reflect that value.

When I debug the view and I submit via the form `@filter[:destination]` contains the value I expect, when I submit via the url (/holiday/spain) @filter[:destination] gives nil.

What's going on?

The view is:

```
<%= form_tag '/holiday/all', id: 'search_form', method: :get do %>
  <div id="location" class="collapse in">
    <div class="padding20">
      <%= text_field :filter, :destination, value: @filter[:destination], class: 'form-control' %>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <br/>
      <%= button_tag class: 'btn-search4', id: 'search_button' do %>
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Search
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

relevant part of routes.rb:

```
  get 'holiday/:location', to: 'holidays#index', as: 'holidays'
```

and finally the controller:

```
page = params[:page] || 1
sort = params[:sort] || {}
@filter = params[:filter] || {}
display_type = params[:display_type] || {}

# set hidden field values
@filter[:duration_min] = @filter[:duration_min] || 1
@filter[:duration_max] = @filter[:duration_max] || 31
@filter[:destination] = params[:location]

@result = Holiday.search type: display_type, page: page, sort: sort, filter: @filter
```

Log after a submit via url:

```
Started GET "/vakantie/Kreta" for ::1 at 2016-04-20 22:41:18 +0200
Processing by HolidaysController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"location"=>"Kreta"}
   (17.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "holidays" WHERE ((upper(city) like upper('%Kreta%') OR upper(region) like upper('%Kreta%') or upper(country) like upper('%Kreta%'))  AND (duration_min >= 1 AND duration_max <= 31 ))
  Holiday Load (3.2ms)  SELECT  "holidays".* FROM "holidays" WHERE ((upper(city) like upper('%Kreta%') OR upper(region) like upper('%Kreta%') or upper(country) like upper('%Kreta%'))  AND (duration_min >= 1 AND duration_max <= 31 ))  ORDER BY id asc LIMIT 12 OFFSET 0
  CACHE (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "holidays" WHERE ((upper(city) like upper('%Kreta%') OR upper(region) like upper('%Kreta%') or upper(country) like upper('%Kreta%'))  AND (duration_min >= 1 AND duration_max <= 31 ))
  Rendered partials/_starrating.html.erb (3.7ms)
  Review Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "reviews".* FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."holiday_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["holiday_id", 804]]
  Rendered partials/_userrating.html.erb (12.0ms)
  Rendered partials/_detail.html.erb (139.4ms)
  Rendered partials/_starrating.html.erb (3.8ms)
  Review Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "reviews".* FROM "reviews" WHERE Completed 200 OK in 1467ms (Views: 1415.5ms | ActiveRecord: 40.5ms)
```

Log after submit via form:

```
Started GET "/vakantie/Spanje?utf8=%E2%9C%93&filter%5Bduration_min%5D=1&filter%5Bduration_max%5D=31&filter%5Bprice_min%5D=1&filter%5Bprice_max%5D=500&filter%5Bdestination%5D=Spanje&button=&filter%5Bdays%5D=1%3B31&filter%5Bprice%5D=1%3B500&filter%5Bis_hotel%5D=false&filter%5Bis_appartement%5D=false&filter%5Bis_aparthotel%5D=false&filter%5Bis_villa%5D=false&filter%5Bis_bungalow%5D=false&filter%5Bis_holidaypark%5D=false&filter%5Bis_camping%5D=false&filter%5Bbus%5D=false&filter%5Bflight%5D=false&filter%5Bself_transportation%5D=false&filter%5Bhas_wifi%5D=false&filter%5Bhas_kids_pool%5D=false&filter%5Bhas_pool%5D=false&filter%5Bhas_supermarket%5D=false&filter%5Bhas_bar%5D=false&filter%5Bhas_parking%5D=false&filter%5Bhas_restaurant%5D=false&filter%5Bservice_logies%5D=false&filter%5Bservice_breakfast%5D=false&filter%5Bservice_halfpension%5D=false&filter%5Bservice_allinclusive%5D=false&filter%5Bstars_five%5D=false&filter%5Bstars_four%5D=false&filter%5Bstars_three%5D=false&filter%5Bstars_two%5D=false&filter%5Bstars_one%5D=false&sort%5Bname%5D=Naam&sort%5Bprice%5D=Prijs" for ::1 at 2016-04-20 22:49:21 +0200
Processing by HolidaysController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "filter"=>{"duration_min"=>"1", "duration_max"=>"31", "price_min"=>"1", "price_max"=>"500", "destination"=>"Spanje", "days"=>"1;31", "price"=>"1;500", "is_hotel"=>"false", "is_appartement"=>"false", "is_aparthotel"=>"false", "is_villa"=>"false", "is_bungalow"=>"false", "is_holidaypark"=>"false", "is_camping"=>"false", "bus"=>"false", "flight"=>"false", "self_transportation"=>"false", "has_wifi"=>"false", "has_kids_pool"=>"false", "has_pool"=>"false", "has_supermarket"=>"false", "has_bar"=>"false", "has_parking"=>"false", "has_restaurant"=>"false", "service_logies"=>"false", "service_breakfast"=>"false", "service_halfpension"=>"false", "service_allinclusive"=>"false", "stars_five"=>"false", "stars_four"=>"false", "stars_three"=>"false", "stars_two"=>"false", "stars_one"=>"false"}, "button"=>"", "sort"=>{"name"=>"Naam", "price"=>"Prijs"}, "location"=>"Spanje"}
   (18.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "holidays" WHERE ((upper(city) like upper('%Spanje%') OR upper(region) like upper('%Spanje%') or upper(country) like upper('%Spanje%'))  AND (duration_min >= 1 AND duration_max <= 31 AND price_max >= 1 AND price_min <= 500 ))
  Holiday Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "holidays".* FROM "holidays" WHERE ((upper(city) like upper('%Spanje%') OR upper(region) like upper('%Spanje%') or upper(country) like upper('%Spanje%'))  AND (duration_min >= 1 AND duration_max <= 31 AND price_max >= 1 AND price_min <= 500 )) LIMIT 12 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: It'd help much if we could reproduce the problem.

Comment: what is params[:location]?

Comment: and can you provide the server log after you submit?

Comment: @ZhiliangTakutoXing params[:location] holds the part of the url that has the search value

Comment: ok, now I understand the question. Can you provide the server logs like this `Started GET "/holiday/spain" for ::1 at 2016-04-20 16:43:00 -0400
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"location"=>"spain"}` after you type your url?

Comment: Is the problem between the routes and the controller or between the controller and the view? What I mean is, from the controller, is `params[:location]` nil? If it is not nil, then can you try setting a new variable `@destination` in the controller and using it from the view (just while debugging) instead of `@filter[:destination]`. That will help narrow down where the issue is

Comment: @alexanderbird issue is indeed between controller and view. I'm a bit further now, in the view @filter[:destination] is nil, but @filter['destination'] has the value I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a symbol/string issue, you can convert the `Hash` to `HashWithIndifferentAccess` using [`Hash#with_indifferent_access`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) from the controller.

So matching strings and keys refer to the same value instead of different values

Comment: In the model I did a `stringify_keys!` on the parameter of the method expecting that that would only be applied with that method ... but it didn't. Your answer put me on the right track.

Comment: Great, glad to help! Also I believe `stringify_keys!` changes the hash but `stringify_keys` returns a modified hash and leaves the old one untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Use `text_field_tag` instead of `text_field` in the form